# In Django, which directory should static files be?

Tags: python, django, heroku

I have my static files in sub_app directory. I will name the folder `sub_app` where `view.py`, `model.py` are located. And when I run `python manage.py findstatic` it returns  `sub_app\static` folder.
I have another folder name as main_app, where `settings.py` file is located. These two folders and `manage.py` file is located in a root folder.
I have no issue when `DEBUG=True`, but when I run `DEBUG=False`, I got following warning

```
venv\lib\site-packages\whitenoise\base.py:115: UserWarning: No directory at: root\static\
  warnings.warn(u"No directory at: {}".format(root))
```

Here are static files settings

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

Where should my static files?

Answer (score 2):

You can put your static files anywhere, as long as you let your application know where they are. You have it configured that

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

but you say that you have your static files in `sub_app\static`. The error is telling you that it's checking the root folder. You need to change your configuration to

```
STATIC_URL = '/sub_app/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/sub_app/static'
```

Comment: should i change STATIC_ROOT  to `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'sub_app/static')` or `'/sub_app/static'` ?

Comment: /sub_app/static means look in the root for a directory called sup_app, and then look within that directory for a directory called static. There should be no need to define that it's within the base directory as it's already looking in the root

Comment: my directory is like `D:\abc\efg\root`, if i put `'/sub_app/static'`, my directory became ` D:\sub_app\static\` which is not a valid dir

Comment: To clarify, it will look in the root directory of you project. Not your computer's root directory.

Answer (score 0):

*Create a directory named **static** inside the app directory where the "view.py, model.py are located."
Inside **static** you need to create another directory with the **same name** as of the app.*
Inside that folder you can create your static files which include anything like your css files

Just add this line in the settings.py of your app

**STATIC_URL = '/static/'**

As you mentioned sub_app
you should create sub_app/static/sub_app directory.